# Which come next in these visual logic sequences?

Tags: visual, sequence

I took these puzzles from Jim Barrett's book How to Pass Advance Aptitude Tests.

I found this bunch not that obvious to answer. Can you help me find the right choice for each sequence and explain your reasoning?

I am going to share the solutions with you afterwards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/How-Pass-Advanced-Aptitude-Tests/dp/B00NBDUSTQ/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=how+to+pass+advanced+aptitude+test&qid=1632696466&sr=8-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give brief pointers rather than outright solutions.

Q24. The circle and the cross are moving separately. Continue the motion of both.

Q27. Same again; don't be deceived by the fact that sometimes one of them is in front of the other.

Q30. One answer corresponds to a repeating cycle of length 3; I don't find this very satisfactory but don't see anything better either.

Q33. Once again we have two things moving separately, one of them sometimes obscuring the other.

Q36. And again!

Q36. And again! The tricky bit is that one of the moving things is not a *diameter of the circle* but a *white semicircle* which sometimes obscures the small circle.

Comment: I agree that Q30 isn't very satisfying, but worth pointing out that, just like all the others, there are two visual elements (vertical line and circle) that are moving separately.

Answer (score 2):

Just for #38, there's a mildly intuitive flip of symmetry for the dot working out from the center.  #2 a diagonal reflection of #4 and #1 with answer b.

A semi circle moving around should cover up answer b's black dot.

Maybe you are supposed to be imagining a 3D rotation, the blank center has the black dot on the 'other side' of the sphere?  Like a striped billiard with a dimple.

Something like rotate 90° on the axis normal to the horizontal line, then 90° CCW along our viewing axis.
In the center the dot is on the 'other side', top right.

Comment: That is a good intuition. It might just be that every second change the dot decides to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

All of them are a repeating pattern of 4. In your answer you said you were having difficulty with Q30 and Q38.

Q30 - consider the horizontal line as being stationary. Now:

- Ball - right, left, middle, right, ..left
- Vertical line - left, middle, right, left, ...middle

> - horizontal line, with a ball on left and line in middle = d

Q38 - consider the circle as being stationary. Now:

- Ball - topLeft, bottomRight, invisible, topLeft, ...bottomRight
- Line - vertical, horizontal, vertical, horizontal, ...vertical

> - bottomRight ball, vertical line = b

Answer (score 1):

The answers are:

> 24D 27B 30D 33A 36B 38B

Had to post here to include the image. I followed Gareth's brilliant answer. I guess the biggest takeaway is that you have to consider a puzzle for its single elements, rather then force relationships between them. Once the logic is clear is pretty simple to break down.

However I still don't understand Q30 ad I have trouble with Q38 as you can see.

> [image: solution]

Comment: The allegedly correct answer to 30 is the one that makes the sequence a repeating cycle of length 3. This makes good sense for the vertical bar at the bottom; the position of the "ball" at the top is more arbitrary. I think it's just not a very good question.

Comment: On reflection I have trouble with 38 too (and not only because I wrote its number as 36 in my answer, duh). I think perhaps we're again supposed to suppose a _period-3_ motion for the black circle. If so, then again I think it's just not a very good question.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I see it now for both 30 and 38. There is an interesting logic about cycle, sequence length and pattern repetition.